# Angular 5: "NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2" on Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I like to build my own UI library for Angular 5. I've oriented myself on Angular Material and tried to build a simple button Component. On compile time it works fine but when I use the library in a project I get the runtime error `NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2`

I have no idea what's wrong. Do I have to import a special module or something?

Below you'll find my component class:

```
import { FocusMonitor } from "@angular/cdk/a11y";
import { Platform } from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnDestroy, Renderer2, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * Base class for further classes.
 */
export class MyButtonBase {
    constructor(public _renderer: Renderer2, public _elementRef: ElementRef) { }
}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "button[my-button], button[my-secondary-button]",
    exportAs: "myButton",
    host: {
        "[disabled]": "disabled || null",
    },
    templateUrl: "button.html",
    styleUrls: ["button.css"],
    inputs: ["disabled"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    preserveWhitespaces: false,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyButton extends MyButtonBase implements OnDestroy {

    constructor(renderer: Renderer2, elementRef: ElementRef, private _platform: Platform, private _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor) {
        super(renderer, elementRef);
        this._focusMonitor.monitor(this._elementRef.nativeElement, this._renderer, true);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._focusMonitor.stopMonitoring(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
    }

    public focus(): void {
        this.getHostElement().focus();
    }

    private getHostElement(): any {
        return this._elementRef.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to run it locally?

Comment: @AlejandroMorán It depends, when you use the @angular/cli you can use the flag --preserve-symlinks. Alternatively you can use [install-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local). It install without symlinks.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with webpack. When installing it from a local file path this error happens. When I publish it and install it via npm it works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

update constructor(renderer: Renderer2  to  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2 ?